# NDK r16 changes the section header of the so file

Tags: android, android-ndk

[image: diff ccreenshot]

After applying NDK r16, the section header of the prebuilt so file changes when building the application.

In the attached figure, the left is the original, and the right is the file with the section header changed.

Returning the NDK to r15c, removes this issue.

Is it possible to fix this issue by giving options with NDK r16 applied?

Thanks.

Comment: I see the difference, but why is the r16 header wrong?

Comment: Are you using GCC?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ELF parsing tool you can see the diff is ".note.gnu.build-id". Look for "--build-id" in [link](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html#Options) for more details.
Although it seems there is no way to avoid generating this by NDK. It is found you can produce a same id with:
1. The source code is located in the same place including all of it's dependencies (in terms of drive path)
2. Android-NDK is located in the same place